# how to move specific files based on a key and rename them

Tags: bash, scripting

I have over 100000 files.

for example, I mentioned 3 files below

```
bcbb79d8-1d4a-4fbb-b16c-4df86839773e.htseq.counts.gz
bcdc68db-c874-4097-9c46-b06e331caaf5.htseq.counts.gz
bd4b6975-90d9-43f8-aadc-344d04644822.htseq.counts.gz
```

I have a text file named key.txt with the following information.

```
File Name                                                 ID
bcbb79d8-1d4a-4fbb-b16c-4df86839773e.htseq.counts.gz    TCCC-06-0210
bcdc68db-c874-4097-9c46-b06e331caaf5.htseq.counts.gz    TCHA-27-2519
bd4b6975-90d9-43f8-aadc-344d04644822.htseq.counts.gz    TCHU-76-4929
```

I want to take only those files that their name are in the key , move them to a new folder and change their name to the ID.

Comment: `while read -r fname id; do [ -f "$fname" ] && mv "$fname" "/path/to/move/to"; done < key.txt` (untested) You can add `while read -r fname id || [ -n "$fname" ]; do ...` if there is a chance `key.txt` does not have a POSIX eof to make sure you get the last line in the file.

Comment: @David C. Rankin should I use fname for each file name ?

Comment: Hold on, I'm writing it up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a little more of a write up rather than a comment would be helpful. The approach to take is to read the filename (`fname`) and ID (`id`) from each line in `key.txt` and then *validate* that `fname` is a file and does exist, and then move the file in `"$fname"` to whatever `"/path/to/move/to/$id"` you need.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

## read each line into variables fname and id (handle non-POSIX eof)
while read -r fname id || [ -n "$fname" ]; do
    ## test that "$fname" is a file, and if so, move to destination
    [ -f "$fname" ] && mv "$fname" "/path/to/move/to/$id"
done < key.txt
```

(**note:** a POSIX end-of-file (`eof`) is simply the final `'\n'` at the end of the last line. Some editors do not enforce it and it will cause your read to miss the final line of data unless you check that `"$fname"` was filled with data (is non-empty) -- the `[ -n "$fname" ]` added to the end of the `white read -r ...`)

You are feeding the loop with a redirection of `key.txt`. Each iteration of the `while` loop will read a new line from `key.txt` into the variables `fname` and `id` (word-splitting on the default *Internal Field Separator* (`IFS`). After the read and separation into `fname` and `id`, you simply verify `$fname` holds a valid filename (in the current working directory) and then `mv` the file where you want it.

You should execute the script in the directory containing the files, or append a relative or absolute filename to where they are located to `"$fname"`.

**Example**

Here is a short example that may help clear things up:

The `move_rename.sh` script:

```
$ cat move_rename.sh
#!/bin/bash

## read each line into variables fname and id (handle non-POSIX eof)
while read -r fname id || [ -n "$fname" ]; do
    ## test that "$fname" is a file, and if so, move to destination
    [ -f "$fname" ] && mv "$fname" "dest/$id.txt"
done < key.txt
```

The `key.txt` file:

```
$ cat key.txt
File Name                                                 ID
bcbb79d8-1d4a-4fbb-b16c-4df86839773e.htseq.counts.gz    TCCC-06-0210
bcdc68db-c874-4097-9c46-b06e331caaf5.htseq.counts.gz    TCHA-27-2519
bd4b6975-90d9-43f8-aadc-344d04644822.htseq.counts.gz    TCHU-76-4929
```

File locations before script execution. (dest) is the directory to move to. (that is `ls -one` output not `ls -L(lowercase)`, the `ls -al` is `L(lowercase))

```
$ ls -1
dest
bcbb79d8-1d4a-4fbb-b16c-4df86839773e.htseq.counts.gz
bcdc68db-c874-4097-9c46-b06e331caaf5.htseq.counts.gz
bd4b6975-90d9-43f8-aadc-344d04644822.htseq.counts.gz
key.txt
move_rename.sh

$ ls -al dest
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 Jan 17 20:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 david david 12288 Jan 17 20:05 ..
```

Execute the script

```
$ bash move_rename.sh
```

Working directory contents after execution

```
$ ls -1
dest
key.txt
move_rename.sh
```

Contents of `dest` after execution.

```
$ ls -al dest
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jan 17 20:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 4096 Jan 17 20:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan 17 19:59 TCCC-06-0210.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan 17 19:59 TCHA-27-2519.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan 17 19:59 TCHU-76-4929.txt
```

Comment: I ran your code like this but nothing happened I called it move_rename.sh then I put it to the folder that I have all the files . then I went with terminal there and I did this  `chmod +x move_rename.sh` then I did this ./move_rename.sh but no error and no move

Comment: What did you put in for `/path/to/move/to`? (note the change to move to `/path/to/move/to/$id` to change the name to `ID`.) If there were no errors and no move, that means it is not seeing `$fname` as a filename and the `[ -f "$fname" ]` test is most likely failing. Double check everything -- it will do what you want.

Comment: before, I ran your script. I renamed the `File Name` in the key.txt to `fname` and `ID` to `id` I also put the path like this "/Users/admin/Desktop/newfolder$id"

Comment: I found the issue. can you please also tell me how to add an extenstion of .txt to the end of each files too? I will accept and like your answer . thanks again

Comment: No need to rename `File Name` or `ID`, since `File Name` isn't a file it will be skipped.

Comment: No problem. Just add `"/path/to/move/to/$id.txt"` or `"$fname.txt"` (whichever you need to add the `".txt"` to.

Comment: thanks, one of the problem is that it copy some of the files on desktop althought I gave the right direction to a folder :-))))

Comment: Did you **quote** everything in **double-quotes**? The only way anything gets moved to desktop is if there is a `space` in your destination path like `/path/to/desktop dir/location/$id.txt` and you fail to quote. Then the file will be moved to `/path/to/desktop`

Comment: does it matter if the files are Document or .gz? I put the key.txt and the move_rename.sh in the folder that all the data are there. then I run it in that folder but I don't know why once works and once does not

Comment: Nope, bash just takes the filename as whatever you tell it it is. It could be `"any.old-funny_file.gz.tar.acd with sugar-on-top"` and if you quote and if the file exists, bash will handle it `:)` If once worked and once did not, you probably already move the files that did not. I'll add a short example to the answer.

Comment: those files that are not moved to the folder, they get the name of `newfolder` the name of the destination folder + the ID + a question mark does it make any sense ?

Comment: Umm no. Click on the lets go to chat button and I'll help you though it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163369/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-nik-bernou).